# WHERE clause for different column names

Tags: python, mysql, etl

The script below reflects my updated, edited attempts (following advice below) to populate dimension tables with rows from tables in an operational database providing that the Primary Keys from a PANDAS DataFrame, created from joining ID columns from relevant tables in OPDB, are not present in the Dimension Tables.

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

        ...

op_cursor = op_connector.cursor
dwh_cursor = dwh_connector.cursor

        ...

class dimension_table:  
def __init__(self, dwh_cols, op_cols, dim_id, dwh_table_name, op_table_name,op_args=None, dwh_args=None):
    self.dwh_cols = ('')
    self.op_cols = ('')
    self.dim_id = dim_id
    self.dwh_table_name = dwh_table_name
    self.op_table_name = '`*opdb.*`.' + op_table_name
    self.op_args = ",".join(op_cols)
    self.dwh_args = ",".join(dwh_cols)

        ...


billing_address_data = dimension_table(("id","address", "alias", "postal_code", "type", "city", "country", 
                                       "geolocation"),
                                      ("id","address", "alias", "postal_code", "type", "city", "country", 
                                       "geolocation"),
                                      billing_address_dim_id,'billing_address_dim', 'billing_address')

        ...

def load_dim(instance):
sql = """INSERT INTO {dwh} ({dwh_cols})
         SELECT {op_cols} 
         FROM {op}
         WHERE {pk} NOT IN
            (SELECT {pk} FROM {dwh} WHERE id = %s)
         LIMIT 1
      """
for key in instance.dim_id:

    try:            
        # ID APPEND
        dwh_cursor.execute(sql.format(dwh = instance.dwh_table_name,
                                      dwh_cols = instance.dwh_args,
                                      op_cols = instance.op_args,
                                      op = instance.op_table_name,
                                      pk = 'id'),

                           str(key))

        dwh_connector.commit()

    except mysql.connector.ProgrammingError as err:                         
        # ORDER_ID APPEND
        dwh_cursor.execute(sql.format(dwh = instance.dwh_table_name,
                                      dwh_cols = instance.dwh_args,
                                      op_cols = instance.op_args,
                                      op = instance.op_table_name,
                                      pk = 'order_id'),

                           str(key))

        dwh_connector.commit()

    billing_profile_op_id = dwh_cursor.lastrowid 

      ...

load_dim(order_items_data)
```

My latest problem is the error attributed to running the final line of code in the script,`load_dim(order_items_data)`. 
it is the order_items table with the order_id PK.

> ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, along with the specific error encountered.

Comment: Please add sample data for the SQL table in question.  Also include your current Python code.

Comment: Did you try `WHERE id = '"+str(key)+"' OR  order_id = '"+str(key)+"'`?

Comment: Please add the table structure or some sample data. It is hard to guess with no information about the schema or the data.

Comment: @LeoGer . . . Just that you are asking this suggests a problem with your data model.  Instead of storing repeated values in separate columns, you should store them in separate *rows*.

Comment: Please tag the database you are using and show DB-API with `import` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `try/except` and avoid all the query build and `fetch` checks by using one pure insert-select SQL query with `IN` clause since this reflects the non-duplicate append query need. See [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

Below uses `LIMIT 1` to replace `fetchone()`, otherwise use `TOP 1` or `fetch first 1 rows only` depending on RDBMS. Also, parameter placeholder uses `%s`, otherwise use `?` depending on Python DB-API. In future posts, always tag RDBMS and show the DB-API with `import` lines.

```
def load_dim(instance):
    sql = """INSERT INTO {dwh} ({dwh_cols})
             SELECT {op_cols} 
             FROM {op}
             WHERE {pk} NOT IN
                (SELECT {pk} FROM {dwh} WHERE {pk} = %s)
             LIMIT 1
          """
    for key in instance.dim_id:

        try:            
            # ID APPEND
            dwh_cursor.execute(sql.format(dwh = instance.dwh_table_name,
                                          dwh_cols = instance.dwh_args,
                                          op_cols = instance.op_args,
                                          op = instance.op_table_name,
                                          pk = 'id'),
                               (str(key),))

            dwh_connector.commit()

        except Exception as e:                          # ADJUST TO DB-API SPECIFIC Error
            # ORDER_ID APPEND
            dwh_cursor.execute(sql.format(dwh = instance.dwh_table_name,
                                          dwh_cols = instance.dwh_args,
                                          op_cols = instance.op_args,
                                          op = instance.op_table_name,
                                          pk = 'order_id'),
                               (str(key),))

            dwh_connector.commit()

        billing_profile_op_id = dwh_cursor.lastrowid    # RETURNS 0 IF NO DATA APPENDED
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not quite there yet so have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: My mistake. For parameter argument in `cursor.execute`, pass `str(key)` as a tuple or list (not scalar): `(str(key),)` or `[str(key)]`. See my edits.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, it solved the problem I had there at hand, unfortunately however, it unearthed another error in my script as described in my edited question.

Comment: In the SQL string, change `WHERE id = %s` to `WHERE {pk} = %s`

Comment: Fantastic! Great to hear and glad to help!